# Styled components: select div within div within current element

Tags: css, css-selectors, styled-components

I have a styled component modal that has several divs as childs. I need to style the div in the second level.

```
<StyledComponentModal>
 <div>
  <div> // <-- This one needs styling
    // ...
  </div>
 </div>
</StyledComponentModal
```

How can I select that `div`?

I tried using `div div`:

```js
const Modal = styled(MyModal)`
  background: transparent;
  height: auto;
  margin: ${rem(0)} auto;
  margin-top: 25vh;
  width: 90vw;

  div div {
    /* doesn't work :( */
  }
`;
```

I also tried other stuff like `&div div` etc. but can't get it to work.

How do I select and style that div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
> div > div {

}
```

works.